# Override the base target="_top" for link in visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, html5

There are lot of links in my page. Of which most of them are to be opened in the same tab so, i have set the base target="_top" but For particular columns of link i need to open them in new tab. 
Please, tell me how to override this html functionality in my vf page.

TIA!!

Comment: Have you set `target="_blank"` for those link tags and tried?

Comment: yes..but the global html attribute is overriding it..so it is not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="tableid">
  <a target='_top' href="something" class="newTabClass"></a>
  <a href="something"> another anchor</a>
  <a href="something"> another anchor</a>
 <a href="something"> another anchor</a>
 </div>

 <script>
    function addTargetTolinks()
    {
        var anchors = document.getElementById('tableid').getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i in anchors) {
            if(anchors[i].className != 'newTabClass') 
                 anchors[i].setAttribute("target", "_top");
        }
    }
    addTargetTolinks();
   </script>
```

By using this you can set the target to all anchor inside tableId except the anchor with newTabClass class